# Does "Eso no es nada" mean "That is nothing" or does it mean "That is not nothing"?

Tags: traducción, gramática

In "Treasure Island", there is this passage:

> "This is nothing," he said as soon as he had closed the door. "I have
>   drawn blood enough to keep him quiet awhile; he should lie for a week
>   where he is--that is the best thing for him and you; but another
>   stroke would settle him."

The Spanish translation is:

> --Eso no es nada, dijo en cuanto hubo cerrado tras de sí la puerta. Le he sacado sangre suficiente para poderlo mantener bien por bastante
>   tiempo. Debe quedarse por una semana en cama: eso es lo menos malo
>   para él y para Vds.; pero un nuevo ataque le traerá la muerte
>   inevitablemente.

I know that Spanish allows double negatives (which is a "no-no" (no pun intended) in English), but this still seems to be saying, "that is not nothing" (in other words, it *is* something). Am I right?

Comment: good question, but the feedback provided by the users unable to explain this properly is making it more confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spanish *Esto no es nada* is used to downplay a situation or an action. 
Example:

> This is nothing, I have fought in World War II.

I think in the text it means that the blood drawing is nothing compared to what follows next.

Answer (score 4):

A negative adverb or indefinite pronoun or adjective after the verb like *nada, nunca, nadie, ningún<sub>/o/a/os/as</sub>* obligates a negative verb.  These words can themselves negate the verb, in which case no double negative is necessary:

- **No** es **nada**.
  **Nada** es.
- **No** lo hace **nunca**.
  **Nunca** lo hace.

Just saying "Es nada" only works in the noun sense (*la<sub>/el</sub> nada*: nothingness) like *El espacio es nada* and probably won't come up too terrible often (saying *el espacio no es nada* would be denying its existence, rather than stating its existence to be absence of anything).

Answer (score 3):

In Spanish you have to put the negative word *before* the verb. If you don't, then you must put **no** before it.

Therefore:

***nadie** lo vio*, but ***no** lo vio nadie*;
***nada** hizo*, but ***no** hizo nada*;
etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's surprising how so many confusions would be avoided if this were taught this way:

> When the word "no" appears in the sentence, "nada" means "anything" instead of "nothing".

For example, "no es nada" has a "no" inside, so it means `it is not anything`, instead of `it is not-nothing`.

Comment: Muy bien, gracias

Answer (score 0):

It means "that is nothing".

If you want to say "that is not nothing" you should say: *"menos es nada"* or *"es más que nada"*.